# Constraining a type with indexable signature fails on assignment

Tags: typescript

With typescript 4.7.2, the following fails but only when assigning a value:

```
type IndexableByString = { [k: string]: any };

function test<T extends IndexableByString>(target: T, key: string) {
    var prop = target[key]; // passes
    target[key] = prop; // Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'.ts(2536)
}
```

My IDE's intellisense correctly reports that `target` is of type `T extends IndexableByString`, but it still fails. Is this a bug or am I using the index signature wrongly here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to constrain the type of `key` to be only keys of `T`:

```
type IndexableByString = { [k: string]: any };

function test<T extends IndexableByString, K extends keyof T>(target: T, key: K) {
    var prop = target[key]; // passes
    target[key] = prop; // works as expected
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwgDwIYCMA2EBCIDKwATgJZwDmUAvFAN5QDaA1gFxQDOxZ5Aum6nBBQAvgG4AUOIBmAVzgBjYCQD2cKMAicAPABUoKDYnaxEKDNjyFSFADRQA0vuSGExphBDKpUHQD4AFMCoROQQwGw6du4gbPYAlHTiUMlQAG7BUGBEymDU6sGhwMwePKJQAPTlmajs7JpJKUEhYcUgPHlZOWWVUADuykRMxjVOkIoQCOLCQA)

Comment: The key needs to be re-usable with other objects, so constraining it to be the key of T is not very workable.  This question I think is more about the type constraint: changing the type of `target` to `IndexableByString` fixes this, so the index signature is correct.  But why doesn't it work with the type constraint?  Unless I'm missing something here, the inconsistency would seem to indicate that there is a bug -- either it should work to index `target` or it should not, unless there is some assumption TS is making concernting `T` that I'm unaware of

Comment: Whatever type is passed into `T` will be narrower than `IndexableByString`. It cannot be accessed by any `string` anymore but only by keys that appear on `T`.

Comment: Fair point, but it doesn't seem to agree with polymorphism.  The TS docs even indicate that we should constrain the generic so as to access properties defined by the constraint type.  So, intuitively, if a constraint type has an index signature, I'm left to believe that the generic should be interpreted as inheriting or sharing that signature as with any other property, and as we should expect with polymorphism.

Comment: I think this is a potential misunderstanding of what is happening here. `extends` doesn't strictly mean that `T` is a subtype of `IndexableByString` but just that it is assignable to `IndexableByString`. In other words, `T` doesn't take on the type `IndexableByString`, it retains its type but is assignable to `IndexableByString`.

Comment: See the docs at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints

Comment: If it's true that the purpose of a type constraint is to allow us to "constrain [something] to work with any and all types that also have [some defined] property", then should we not expect the same to apply to an index signature of the constraint type?  

I'm not aware of anything that suggests otherwise, or why we should expect the signature to apply when reading a property but not on assignment.

Comment: With more thought, my earlier comments may not hold true. My train of thought earlier was around type compatibility in TS being based on structural typing; compatibility between two types being determined by the assignability of one type onto another. Therefore, the constraint isn't that `T` must inherit from `IndexableByString` but that `T` is assignable to `IndexableByString`; `T` doesn't inherit the index-ability of keys by string but retains its own type within the constraint that all its keys are strings. But you raise something important regarding the error states of getting vs setting.

Comment: I did some more digging and found this behaviour was introduced in `3.5.0-dev.20190413` and made it in a general release in `3.5.1`. I think the PR that introduced this was [30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769). And in the release notes for TS 3.5, the relevant section is "[Fixes to unsound writes to indexed access types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types)". I may update this answer to include the context I've noted here later. In the meantime, the links are available for your own perusal.

Comment: Interesting read.  I think you may have found the cause, although if the issue outlined here is an intentional effect of this change is unclear.  It still seems like we should be able to assert that a constraint is for a type that we may assure is indexable by a string.  But, drawing from this article I was able to get the following signature to work, which is satisfactory:

`func<C extends { [k: symbol]: C[K] }, K extends keyof C>(target: C, key: K)`

You should post this is an answer so I can give you credit!